# Matplotlib: make multiple-panel figure of existing figures?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, figure

I am producing a lot of figures with Matplotlib.pyplot (spatial data) and saving them as png's. I would like to be able to first make the figures (in loops), and then choose a few to put together in a multiple-panel figure, using Matplotlib.

I suppose this would mean re-opening the existing png's, and then putting them together using pyplot.subplots(), but I can't figure out a way to do it.
Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: do you have an example of the code that you have at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what I think you mean:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import image
import numpy as np

# initialise grid of axes
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2)
axes = axes.ravel()

# create fake data
img = [
    '01-img.png',
    '02-img.png',
    '03-img.png',
    '04-img.png',
]

# iterate over axes
for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
    im = image.imread(img[i])
    ax.imshow(im)

plt.show()
```

Use `image.imread` to load the image into a plottable form, then use `ax.imshow` to plot the pixels on the axis

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I can see what this does, but my issue is that I already have the separate sub-panels saved as png's. 
I want to make a multiple-panel figure from those saved png's.

Comment: okay let me edit the answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's almost what I wanted! Now it still shows the axes, which I want invisible, but I think I can figure that out.

Comment: To do that do `plt.axis('off')`